# Can a single SQL connection run concurrent transactions?

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions

I'm trying to get my head around the issue of how multiple transactions interact with the underlying connections that an SQL client library has at its disposal. Some libraries abstract this so you don't have to think about how transactions are handled. However, I want to know what happens in this scenario:

- Suppose we only have a single connection
- Suppose that we want to run 2 transactions concurrently.

Is this possible over a single connection? Or, if we want concurrency, at least the same number of connections is needed?

To make myself clearer, I will write some pseudo-SQL-code, remember that this is running in a single connection:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 1
BEGIN TRANSACTION 2

WITH TRANSACTION 2 DO SOMETHING
WITH TRANSACTION 1 DO SOMETHING ELSE

COMMIT TRANSACTION 1
COMMIT TRANSACTION 2
```

## Further questions

- How is this handled by different vendors?
- How is this handled by MySQL, specifically?
- Is there another way of handling this problem that I'm not aware of?

Comment: No. Only nested transactions are possible in single connection.

Comment: Well, I guess that my question is as simple as that, if you want to turn this comment into an answer and elaborate a little bit more, I will grant you the accepted answer.